# variable scope inside object

Tags: javascript, scope

myObject has two functions, the first one is calling the second one, is there a way to see variable a inside callMe()?

```
var myObj =  {
   callMefirst: function() {
      var thisObj = this;
      var a;
      a = 'chocolate cookie';
      thisObj.callMe();
   },

   callMe: function() {
      alert(a);
   }
}
myObj.callMefirst();
```

otherwise I know I can pass it as a parameter, or set var a in global scope of the object but I'm interested to understand this specific case of scope

Comment: `var this.a` would make it a map(object)-property, and thus selectable from any method in the object (`alert(this.a);`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Since it is defined with the `var` keyword, it is scoped to the function it is defined in. It is therefore only visible to that function and to other functions defined inside that function (of which you have none).

Answer (score 1):

`a` is defined within the `callMefirst` function and exists only here. Remember that JavaScript has functional (lexical) scope. As such, the easiest way to let `callMe` have access to `a` would to be as you suggest and define it within the scope of `myObj`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in multiple ways; the following uses closure.

```
var myObj = (function() {
   var a;

   return{
     callMefirst: function() {
        var thisObj = this;
        a = 'chocolate cookie';
        thisObj.callMe();
     },

     callMe: function() {
        alert(a);
     }
   }
})()
myObj.callMefirst();
```

Using closure with object initiation:

```
var myObjF = function(pass) {
   var a=pass;

   return{
     callMefirst: function() {
        var thisObj = this;
        thisObj.callMe();
     },

     callMe: function() {
        alert(a);
     }
   }
}
var myObj=myObjF("hello");
myObj.callMefirst();
```

Using function as object:

```
var myObjF = function(pass) {
   this.a=pass;

    this.callMefirst = function() {
        var thisObj = this;
        thisObj.callMe();
     };
}
myObjF.prototype.callMe = function() {
    alert(a);
}

var myObj=new myObjF("hello");
myObj.callMefirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var myObj =  {
  a:"",       
  callMefirst: function() {
      var thisObj = this;
      this.a = 'chocolate cookie';
      thisObj.callMe();
   },

   callMe: function() {
      alert(this.a);
   }
}
myObj.callMefirst();
```